# Decoration brace in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have TeX Live 2013 installed via MacTeX on my Snow Leopard laptop.

I copied the following code from page 247 of version 2.10 of `pgfmanual`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {A};
\node (b) at (2,1) {B};
\draw (a) -- (b);
\draw[decorate,decoration=brace] (a) -- (b);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},red] (a) -- (b);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=5pt},blue] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Yet somehow I get this error:

```
./Untitled2.tex:11: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/decorati
on/brace' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \draw[decorate,decoration=brace]
                                      (a) -- (b);
?
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: By default, zero.

Comment: Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

I believe I've found a solution. Use:

```
 \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
```

Comment: Yes, this makes the matter.