# Is there other brace type rather than regular?

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

As title, I use this code `\draw [thick,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=0.5mm},decorate]` this like } but I want [
I don't want to only use the same in my picture, is there other type brace?

I guess parameter could satisfy my requirement, but I don't know what sould I type.

Comment: There are (round) parentheses, (square) brackets, curly braces, angle braces, many them with single or double vertical bars...

Comment: It would be great (as always), to have a minimal compilable example starting from `\documentclass{…}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no other brace-like decorations packaged with tikz-pgf, there are snake-like and spring-like decorations, but depending on what you want it might not be good. If you only need to brace a rectangle-shaped area, the `matrix` library provides "delimiters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no predefined "[" shaped path replacing decoration. See the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) Section 48.3, p.589ff and 99.

But since the "[" shape is a very simple one, you could just draw it directly. If you fancy, you can of course create your own decoration, see section 99.3, p.1003ff. The following is a slight modification of an example from the manual:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{example}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[width=5pt,next state=up]
    { \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{5pt}} }

    \state{up}[width=1pt]
    { \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{5pt}} }

    \state{final}
    {\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}}
}


\tikz[decoration=example]
{
\draw [decorate]
(0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [red,decorate] (0,0) to [out=45,in=135] (3,0);
}

\end{document}
```

produces
[image: output from above latex file]

(general hint: You should mention more clearly that this is a tikz question and give or link an example like [Decoration brace in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153899/decoration-brace-in-tikz) or [Adding underbrace in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/adding-underbrace-in-tikz) .)